# Which is correct linguistically and grammatically?

Tags: grammar

> 1: I am feeling the happiness.
>
> 2: I am feeling happy.

Happy is adjective and happiness is a noun but while speaking both sounds correct. I think Ist one incorrect but most of the people use first while speaking.

Comment: Most of which people? Are you saying you tend to hear "I am feeling the happiness" from people that you know are native speakers of English, or do you mean you hear it from non-native speakers?

Comment: Both are (potentially) acceptable but which one is correct for your situation depends on what you're trying to say... what do you want to convey when you say this?

Answer (score 1):

As a native English speaker, the second option sounds the most correct.  To say how you're feeling is to describe yourself with adjectives, so the proper (and colloquial) way to do this is by saying "happy" instead of "the happiness".

If you're looking for a statement like your second option (I am feeling happy), then you can't switch out "the happiness" for "happy" in this context.  However, if you add to the first option (as @Catija mentioned in their comment), it does work grammatically.  Their example was this:

> I am feeling **the happiness** in this room right now.

This is perfectly acceptable, as long as you describe "the happiness" in some way (e.g. the happiness that is in the room).

Comment: Sure you can... "I'm really feeling the happiness in this room, you are all certainly glad to have won!" You can't feel excitement but people say "I'm feeling the excitement in the air".

Comment: @Catija I forgot about that kind of context, oops! If it's being used in that way, then yes, I totally agree with you, and you're right.  However, as a single statement (like the one the OP was using), "the happiness" does not work. "Happy" cannot be replaced with "the happiness" when you're describing how you yourself are feeling emotionally.

Comment: :D Sure! Also, thanks for not assuming I'm a guy (I'm not).

Comment: @Catija Neither am I, haha! No problem. :)